# Is $ \ {|{n^2\cdot \cos{(n\pi})|}\over {3n^2-5n^3 }} = \ {n^2\over 3n^2-5n^3} $ right?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Is $ \ {|{n^2 \cdot \cos (n\pi)|}\over {3n^2-5n^3 }} = \ {n^2\over 3n^2-5n^3} $ correct? If yes, why?

Comment: Hello, welcome on Math.SE!
Try to tell us about what you have tried on your problem.
What do you know of the sequence $\cos (n \pi)$?

Comment: Hi! i know that cos(npi) = (-1)^n but since it's in the absolute value, it's 1.

Comment: So, problem solved :)

Comment: yes, problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The reason is that $\cos(n\pi)$, where $n$ is an integer, is either $+1$ or $-1$. Thus $|\cos(\pi n)|=1$.

In total,
$$|n^2\cos(n\pi)| = |n^2||\cos(n\pi)| = |n^2| = n^2.$$

Comment: oh yes, got it! Thanks!